# Editing an array of html buttons

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an function that creates an array of html buttons:

```
function getButtons() { // buttons that participants see in the selection phase.
  var trialButtons = [
  '<button class="jspsych-btn" style="color:blue; font-size: 20px; background-color:#CD6155; border-width: 2px; position:absolute; left: 120px; top:20px;  width:210px; height:170px" >%choice%</button>',
  '<button class="jspsych-btn" style="color:blue; font-size: 20px; background-color:#D7BDE2; border-width: 2px; position:absolute; left: 120px; top:220px; width:210px; height:170px" >%choice%</button>',
  '<button class="jspsych-btn" style="color:blue; font-size: 20px; background-color:green;   border-width: 2px; position:absolute; left: 120px; top:420px; width:210px; height:170px" >%choice%</button>',
  '<button class="jspsych-btn" style="color:blue; font-size: 20px; background-color:#F4D03F; border-width: 2px; position:absolute; right:120px; top:20px;  width:210px; height:170px" >%choice%</button>',
  '<button class="jspsych-btn" style="color:blue; font-size: 20px; background-color:#DC7633; border-width: 2px; position:absolute; right:120px; top:220px; width:210px; height:170px" >%choice%</button>',
  '<button class="jspsych-btn" style="color:blue; font-size: 20px; background-color:#BDC3C7; border-width: 2px; position:absolute; right:120px; top:420px; width:210px; height:170px" >%choice%</button>',
  '<button class="jspsych-btn jspsych-btn_instructions" style="position:absolute; left:180px; bottom:30px;" >%choice%</button>'
  ];
  myButtons = [];
  myButtons.push(trialButtons);
  return myButtons[myButtons.length -1];
}
```

How can I manipulate my array to change the style of all the buttons? For example how could I change all the buttons to have `border-color:red`?

Comment: Instead of duplicating tons of style rules, can't you just use a class, and put styles for that class in a CSS stylesheet so you can edit them in one place?

Comment: Is it an option to have an array of button objects instead of an array of strings? E.g. `[{class: 'www', btn_name: 'My button', style: {color: 'blue'}}]` etc? Anything short of that would require some regex to search and replace string patterns.

Comment: @codemonkey I think an array of objects would be okay if I can convert it to a string array eventually, and it's not too burdensome to write all include all the variations (left/right, top, background color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var trialButtons = [
  '<button class="jspsych-btn" style="left: 120px; top:20px;" >%choice%</button>',
  '<button class="jspsych-btn" style="left: 120px; top:220px;" >%choice%</button>',
  '<button class="jspsych-btn" style="left: 120px; top:420px;" >%choice%</button>',
  '<button class="jspsych-btn" style="right:120px; top:20px;" >%choice%</button>',
  '<button class="jspsych-btn" style="right:120px; top:220px;" >%choice%</button>',
  '<button class="jspsych-btn" style="right:120px; top:420px;" >%choice%</button>',
  '<button class="jspsych-btn jspsych-btn_instructions" style="left:180px; bottom:30px;" >%choice%</button>'
  ];


  // TO ADD SOME STYLE::
  trialButtons = trialButtons.map(each => each.replace('style="', 'style="border-color:red; '))
  
  console.log(trialButtons)

  // TO REMOVE SOME STYLE::
  trialButtons = trialButtons.map(each => each.replace('border-color:red; ', ''))
  
  console.log(trialButtons)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do instead of writing down plaintext for buttons, is creating actual elements:

```
const button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerHTML = "%choice%";
button.backgroundColor = "#CD6155";
```

Then you can build upon that and easily say something along the lines of:

```
button.borderColor = "red";
```

Comment: Similar to above I think this gets me 80% of the way there but I'll still need to end of with an array of buttons which have some slight different properties (left/right; top; and background-color)

Comment: @John-Henry what you can do is creating a new seperate variable for each of the buttons (e.g. button0, button1, ..., button6), configure them to your liking and then writing `const trialButtons = [button0, button1, ..., button6];`
This leaves you with an array of buttons you can iterate over with `trialButtons.foreach(button => {//adjustments here})`

Answer (score 1):

Instead Write a code something like this
  and then in Css use it to style it like this

```
.jspysch-btn {color:blue; font-size: 20px; background-color:#CD6155; border-width: 2px; position:absolute; left: 120px; top:20px;  width:210px; height:170px)
```

Then if you want to change any values use

```
document.getElementsByClass("jspysch-btn").style.THINGYOUWISHTOCHANGE = CHANGE;
```

Then if you want to change unique Values per each give each button its own unique ID
`<button id = "UniqueId">`
Then change only its style, you can use these in unison too like

```
document.getElementsByClass("jspysch-btn").style.borderColor = 'red'; 
document.getElementById("UniqueId").style.color = 'blue';
```

Comment: I think this is the right idea, just that I'll need to make 6 buttons, that have similar features, but also have different `left/right`; `top`; and `background-color`

Comment: Well then you can add a special ID for each like ```<button id = "UniqueId">``` and then if you need to change specifically that one use ```document.getElementById("UniqueId").style.change = change;```

Comment: That should make it good, so then you could change all of them using ```document.getElementByClass("jspysch-btn").style.color = 'blue'; ``` and then use ```document.getElementByClass("UniqueID").style.marginLeft = '10px';```